# php parameter passing wrong

Tags: javascript, php, html

In an HTML page I have printed two variables (a and b). I have a button that, when pressed, increments by one the value of the two variables and reload the page passing the new values as parameters. But the new values I receive are 0. Why?

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['a']))
            $a = $GET['a'];             

        if(isset($_GET['b']))     
            $b = $GET['b']; 

        echo ""+$a;
        echo ""+$b;
    ?>


    <input type='button' value='RELOAD' name='reload' onclick='reload(<?php echo $a.",".$b ?>)'>


    <script>
        function reload(a,b)
        {
            document.location.href = "<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?a=".(a+1)."&b=".(b+1);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: `+` is for math, `.` is for concatenation (in PHP)

Comment: Why do you increment the values in JS, why not do that in PHP?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think you closed this question wrong. This is more of a typo than the semantics

Comment: Please update the question with the new code.

Comment: @chris85 you're right, I've changed them. I also removed the $a=1 and $b=2. But now, when I press the button, the values doesn't change at all, as I still have $a=0 and $b=0.

Comment: `echo ""+$a;` is still incorrect. `".(a+1)."` is javascript so I think that should still be `+`s. You should still initialize the values.